# How to highlight countries properly in ios maps swift

Tags: maps, highlighting

I am just trying to fill colors in the various countries of the world.. I was pretty successful in doing so..

But *the fill color is coming out of the boundary of a country*. Could u just suggest me *how to clips to bounds a `MKPolygonRenderer` class object*?

Comment: add the code that you have tried so far

Comment: You can find your answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732637/how-to-highlight-countries-in-ios-maps ,  may be it will help you.